# Unable to "$bundle install" when Generating Rails framework on Cloud 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, cloud9-ide, bundle-install

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial [here](https://github.com/lhofer/CS50_Rails_Seminar/tree/master/todo_list_starting_out) in **cloud9**. After entering `$rails new myproject` I get an error when attempting to  `$bundle install`. part of the error reads

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Tried installing using `$ gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.8.1` but get `extconf failed, exit code 1`

Is there a way to install nokogirir in order for `$bundle install` to succeed? Also, how can I open the mkmf.log file in cloud9 IDE? I tried `c9 mkmf.log` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you, in fact, have zlib installed?

Comment: You should be able to open `mkmf.log` with `vim mkmf.log`

Comment: @philomory how can I check that?

Comment: Depends on what linux distribution you're running on top of; for ubutnu I think `dpkg -l zlib1g-dev` would check whether it was installed, and `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` would install it.

Comment: @philomory that worked in getting nokogiri installed, but now I'm getting an error when calling `$ bundle install` or even trying to create a new rails project. Error: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:111:in initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/specifications/nokogiri-1.6.8.1.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)` Already tried `sudo chmod -R 1777 /tmp`

Comment: You've installed `rvm` as a multi-user install, which, personally, I try to avoid doing. Looking at the [rvm documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#2-load-rvm-into-your-shell-sessions-as-a-function), you'll need to add any user who's allowed to use `rvm` the rvm user group.

Comment: `(Errno::EACCES)` means you can't write to that directory, you can try installing the gem as root i.e `sudo ...`